# Using jspm and SystemJS to bundle modules based on DOM elements

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

In looking through the jspm and SystemJS docs and examples, it seems that many of the use cases pertain only to bundling JavaScript for Single Page Applications. The implication is that it suffices to have a single, or a few preset bundles.

#### Use Case: Multipage Website

I'm looking to incorporate ES2015 modules and syntax for a large, multipage website whose pages have a range of different dependencies.

---

*With each page request, I want to gather a list of HTML attributes, determine the corresponding modules for those attributes, and create a bundle with **only** the particular dependencies that the page requires.*

---

Some of these pages may require `jquery`, while others might require `d3`. The single point of entry becomes kind of a moot point, because the points of entry may vary depending on which modules the page requires.

It's straightforward enough to gather the list of necessary modules for the page, but it isn't evident to me how I can dynamically produce a bundled file with a huge range of possible dependencies. I've read the [`jspm` docs](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md) several times over, but find it lacking in practical examples with regard to some of the features that may (or may not) be crucial to my particular implementation (e.g., depCache, bundle-sfx).

#### Bundling for Production

My attempt at bundling the particular modules I need for production involved first using `System.import()` to load a list of all the modules that I need to load and then using the promise in the `then` callback to import **only those specific modules**.

**index.html**

```
<script>
  System.import('/src/js/initr.config.js').then(function(m) {
    m.modulesToImport.forEach(function(m) {
        return System.import(m);
    });
  });
</script>
```

This seems to load the required tree of dependencies during development. I've included this as part of `index.html` and it seems to be working for development mode.

However, if I remove this bit of code from `index.html` and place it into my "entry point" (`src/main`) and run `jspm bundle src/main.js public/bundle.js`, my bundle only consists these import statements:

**public/bundle.js**

```
System.registerDynamic("src/main.js", [], false, function($__require, $__exports, $__module) {
  var _retrieveGlobal = System.get("@@global-helpers").prepareGlobal($__module.id, null, null);
  (function() {
    System.import('/src/js/initr.config.js').then(function(m) {
      m.modulesToImport.forEach(function(m) {
        return System.import(m);
      });
    });
  })();
  return _retrieveGlobal();
});
```

Clearly this bundle does not sufficiently compile my code as it only consists of the contents of `src/main` and not the modules imported from within.

This indicates to me that my entry point must consist of es2015, commonjs, etc. import statements, rather than just `System.import()`. But these modules import statements do support dynamic loading. More specifically, if I replaced `System.import(m)` above with `import m`, the file would error.

---

To ask a singular, pointed question:

**Is it possible with `jspm` or `SystemJS` to create a dynamically generated bundle for a large range of module combinations on a multipage website? As these bundles may consist of hundreds of different modules combinations tied to DOM elements, it is not possible for these bundles to be preset or predetermined.**

If it helps, you can view the [repo](https://github.com/matt-mcdaniel/jspm-project-setup) for this project.